# iText 5 java - TextField aligment and options change when editing

Tags: java, itext, textfield, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a multilined TextField with iText5. My problem is that the text I set via field.setText() appears formatted as I wish but **as soon as I click into the field, the field does not have ALIGN_TOP and MULTILINED anymore**. When i leave the "Editing-Mode" my defaulttext is formatted pretty again. The manually entered text is never formatted the way I defined it. I could not find any solution to this so far and I hope someone can help me here... This is what I try to do atm:

```
 TextField kidField = new TextField(writer, box ,null);
    kidField.setText("This is a text");
    kidField.setFont(inside_textbox.getBaseFont());
    kidField.setFontSize(inside_textbox.getSize());
    kidField.setExtraMargin(5,0);
    if(multiLined){
        kidField.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        kidField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
    }

    PdfFormField field = kidField.getTextField();
    field.setFieldName(fieldName);
    writer.addAnnotation(field);
```

The code forms a method to create all my TextFields. writer is a PdfWriter and box is my Rectangle (nothing special about it, it has a BOX-Border of 0.3f and BorderColor Black). "multiLined" is a boolean to indicate whether the field has several lines or not.

I also tried to leave out the setExtraMargin and shuffled to code around in several ways. Output stays the same :(

Comment: I presume you are manually editing the fields using some version of Adobe Reader? Have you tried filling in the field with a different reader, e.g. Foxit?

Comment: Yes, i use Acrobat Reader DC. I just tried to edit my PDF in Foxit Reader 7.2 but the same problem appears.